# Showing that $x \ast y := x + y - \lfloor x + y \rfloor$ defines a group structure on $[0, 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define $x\ast y = x+y - \lfloor x+y \rfloor$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function.

How do I prove that $([0,1),\ast)$ is a group?

I was trying to separate cases and prove this, but it didn't work at all.

Would someone please give me a hint?

Comment: You prove it by the propositions that the set has to satisfy to be classified as a group.

Comment: @JulianRachman Yes, but I have a trouble proving that it is associative..

Comment: Why not show us exactly what you tried, and what went wrong, and we'll see just what needs to be done to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing an explicit isomorphism between this group and the quotient of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ by the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't too bad.

Alternatively, you can always split into cases according to whether each of the expressions $\lfloor x + y \rfloor$ is $0$ or $1$, that is, whether $x + y < 1$ or $x + y \geq 1$. Then, within each case, the floor operations, which are what make an explicit computation tricky, simply don't occur.